# Expression Bodied methods cannot be able to directly call foreach in it

Tags: foreach, c#-6.0

How can I described a method body like this with expression-bodied way?

```
void SomeMethod() =>
  foreach(int value in ListOfInt)
    collect += count;
```

Comment: where are `collect` and `count` from? Class members?

Comment: @qxg, same place as `ListOfInt`

Answer (score 1):

As its name suggested, it's an expression at first. An expression is evaluated to a value, while your `SomeMethod` doesn't. You can argue that it does return a `void` and it's valid in C#. The point is do expression-bodies methods make your code more readable. If not, don't use it.

Instead of converting to expression bodies method directly, it makes more sense to simplify current code. Given only piece of code in question, it can be written

```
collect += ListOfInt.Count() * count;
```

If count is calculated from value, then it can be

```
collect += ListOfInt.Select( value => ...calculate count ...).Sum();
```

or leverage [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for complex logic.

The trick is to convert `foreach` statement to expression. Then converting whole method to expression is easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ForEach method as expression-body instead. Now your expression would look like this:

```
void SomeMethod() => ListOfInt.ForEach(value => {collect+=count;});
```

Comment: `List<T>.ForEach()` is not part of LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to not use an expression bodied function e.g.

```
void SomeMethod()
{
  foreach(int value in ListOfInt)
    collect += count;
}
```